# Clicks only work on the center of elements, what's happening?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

[image]

I'm using [React-Beatiful-DnD](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/), as shown in the attached GIF, clicks only work on the center of the elements. I want clicks to also work on the edges of elements...

In this case, what keywords should I search for to solve the problem?

My code is as follows (simplified)

```
<div {...dragableHandleProps}>
    <Button />
</div>
```

The Button component is from https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/button
But anyway, the click event is captured by the div tag

Comment: The gray part is div or button? i mean, i think the button is only the dots

Comment: @Adrián The gray part is the buttons.